# Unable to use LaTex in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

The below code fails on Jupyter Notebook.

```
$$ \alpha + \frac{\beta}{\gamma} = \delta $$
```

File "", line 1
    $$ \alpha + \frac{\beta}{\gamma} = \delta $$
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to directly enter and display markdown in a regular code cell. You can't do that. You have to turn it into a markdown cell first.

Jupyter has at least two kinds of cells: code cells and markdown cells. The default for a cell is a code cell.

To change it to a markdown cell, select the cell while in meta mode (not with the active cursor in the cell) and press m. You can also turn it into a markdown cell using the menu. Enter the markdown and it will display the way you expect.

You actually can put markdown in a code cell, but the cell will only be allowed to contain markdown and no other code. Use the jupyter magic in the first line for this like so:

```
%%markdown
```

Similarly if you want just latex in a code cell:

```
%%latex
```

Technically you *can* mix markdown with code in a code cell, you just can't enter it directly. Put it into a `IPython.display.Markdown` object.  Like this:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

m  = Markdown('some $markdown$')
display(m)
```

[Here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebook.html#markdown-cells) and [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html) and [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html) and also [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) for more info.